# How to store specific links as a list and then click them

Tags: python, html, list, matrix, web-scraping

I've been following a tutorial on how to web scrape the webpage  http://kanview.ks.gov/PayRates/PayRates_Agency.aspx. The turorial can be found here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/better-web-scraping-in-python-with-selenium-beautiful-soup-and-pandas-d6390592e251. The layout of this is similar to the website I want to scrape for information: https://www.giiresearch.com/topics/TL11.shtml. My only issue is that the links on the giiresearch website for the report titles do not follow a chronological order, eg. the following are from gii research

```
a href="/report/an806147-fixed-mobile-convergence-from-challenger-operators.html">Fixed-Mobile Convergence from Challenger Operators: Case Studies and Analysis</a>

a href="/annual/an378138-convergence-strategies.html">Convergence Strategies</a>
```

The links on kanview website follow an order, eg.

```
a id="MainContent_uxLevel2_JobTitles_uxJobTitleBtn_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$uxLevel2_JobTitles$ctl03$uxJobTitleBtn','')">Academic Advisor</a

a id="MainContent_uxLevel2_JobTitles_uxJobTitleBtn_2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$uxLevel2_JobTitles$ctl04$uxJobTitleBtn','')">Academic Program Specialist</a>
```

This means I can't use the method used in their line of code for my project:

```
python_button = driver.find_element_by_id('MainContent_uxLevel2_JobTitles_uxJobTitleBtn_' + str(x))
```

I have tried to find_elements_by_class_name but all the links have the same class name of 'list title' and so the for loop only opens the first link and doesn't go any further.

I was thinking there should be a way to store the report title links in a list so that I could open them one by one to retrieve more information about each report and save it in an excel sheet.

This is a project where I want to compile an excel sheet of competitor reports with stats on their titles, price, publisher, published date, etc. for market analysis.

Heres my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
import os

#launch url
url = "https://www.giiresearch.com/topics/TL11.shtml"

# create a new Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

#Selenium hands the page source to Beautiful Soup
soup_level1=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')


datalist = [] #empty list
x = 0 #counter

#Beautiful Soup finds all Job Title links on the agency page and the loop begins
for link in soup_level1.find_all("div", {"class": "list_title"}):

    #Selenium visits each Job Title page
    python_button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('list_title')
    python_button.click() #click link

    #Selenium hands of the source of the specific job page to Beautiful Soup
    soup_level2=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

    #Beautiful Soup grabs the HTML table on the page
    table = soup_level2.find_all('table')[0]

    #Giving the HTML table to pandas to put in a dataframe object
    df = pd.read_html(str(table),header=0)

    #Store the dataframe in a list
    datalist.append(df[0])

    #Ask Selenium to click the back button
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")

    #increment the counter variable before starting the loop over
    x += 1

    #end loop block

#loop has completed

#end the Selenium browser session
driver.quit()

#combine all pandas dataframes in the list into one big dataframe
result = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(datalist[i]) for i in range(len(datalist))],ignore_index=True)

#convert the pandas dataframe to JSON
json_records = result.to_json(orient='records')

#pretty print to CLI with tabulate
#converts to an ascii table
print(tabulate(result, headers=["Report Title","Publisher","Published Date","Price"],tablefmt='psql'))

#get current working directory
path = os.getcwd()

#open, write, and close the file
f = open(path + "\\fhsu_payroll_data.json","w") #FHSU
f.write(json_records)
f.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. A minimal, complete code example of what you tried would help us help you. See [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can store the report title links by using the relationship of the child `a` tag element to the parent class within a css selector. Whilst you can get the titles from the pages visited you could also gather tuples within the list comprehension `[(link.get_attribute('href') , link.text) for link in .......`
Then unpack into separate tuples that can be looped.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.giiresearch.com/topics/TL11.shtml'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
titles, links = zip(*[(link.text, link.get_attribute('href')) for link in WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".list_title a")))]) #separate tuples
dates = [item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.plist_dateinfo .plist_info_dd2')]
data = list(zip(dates, titles, links))
```

You can then loop the `links` tuple and `driver.get` each individual one.

You have the titles and dates info in case you want to do anything else. For example:

```
print(data[3])
```

gives

```
('January 30, 2019', 'Global Telco Converged Plans & Bundles Insights 2019: A Look at Bundling Strategies from Around the World', 'https://www.giiresearch.com/report/wise780587-global-telco-converged-plans-bundles-insights-look.html')
```